# so much so that vs. so that

Tags: prepositions, parts-of-speech

CGEL by Huddleston & Pullum (Page 1537) has this example

> (d) *So* as head of clause with dependent modifiers or complements
>
> [64] ii *The Coo-ee cordial factory prospered almost at once, so much **so** that my father bought a new house at Coorparoo.*

And at the bottom of the next page, CGEL calls ***so*** in [64] a pro-form as follows:

> In [64] ***so*** is the head of a clause; clauses normally have a verb as head, but ***so*** lacks the important inflectional properties of verbs. Overall, then, we prefer to classify anaphoric *so* simply as a pro-form; its properties are unquestionably unique, and we do not believe that anything is gained by forcing it into one or more of our general part-of-speech categories.

Now, two pages later, CGEL has this example:

> [72] iii *There had been a power failure, **so** that all classes had had to be cancelled.*
>
> In [72iii] ***so*** is a preposition functioning as head of a result adjunct.

I wonder how and why you should distinguish the two so's as in CGEL. If ***so*** in the first example is a pro-form, shouldn't ***so*** in the second example be a pro-form, as opposed to a preposition?

Comment: They're different entities. 'So much so [that]' means 'to the degree [that]'. 'So that' means 'with the result that'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Doesn't _so_ in _so that_ refer back to the main clause?

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/so-that) labels _so that_ a [compound] conjunction expressing [almost always] purpose. I did X so that Y would happen.

Comment: There are a lot of idiomatic compounds. I remember a paper by (I think) Lakoff and Ross called "A criterion for verb phrase consistency, or Why you can't _do so_ into the sink", which contrasted differential behaviors of the verbal anaphors _do so, do it,_ and _do that_. Very early generative semantics, lots of data.

Comment: I'd have said the same as Edwin already did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example 64**

> [64] The Coo-ee cordial factory prospered almost at once, so much so that my father bought a new house at Coorparoo.

In the sentence above the word *so* is taking the place of a clause. If we reinsert the clause in place of *so*,  it will read:

> The Coo-ee cordial factory prospered almost at once, so much ***did the Coo-ee cordial factory prosper*** that my father bought a new house at Coorparoo.

[Notice here that the clause following *that* is not related to the *so* that we replaced. It is a dependent of the initial degree adverb *so* at the very beginning of the clause. The sentence is similar in structure to:

- **So** fast did it go **that we could not catch it**.]

**Example 72**

> There had been a power failure, so that all classes had had to be cancelled.

Here the word *so* does not represent a clause. In fact it is appearing *between* two clauses:

- [There had been a power failure] so [that all classes had had to be cancelled.]

The word *so* here belongs with the second subordinate clause, of which it is the head. This *so* is different from the one in (64). In (64), the pro-clause *so* was not related to the clause following it. We showed that, in  fact, the clause following *so* in that construction is actually a dependent of the earlier degree adverb *so*. However here, in example (74), the following clause *is* directly related to the word *so*. This is because the word *so* tells us that the classes being cancelled is a result of what was described in the main clause.

The *so* in (74), therefore, is a very different beast from the one in (64). Nonetheless, it still has some similarities. Apart from sounding the same, both have an anaphoric relationship with what has been said before. However, in (74), the word *so* is not a pronoun, pro-verb, or pro-clause. It is merely a resultative preposition.

Comment: In your last paragraph, you say "both have an anaphoric relationship with what has been said before". Isn't such an anaphoric relationship what makes a form a pro-form? You've already acknowledged that it's a pro-form and then claim that (74)'s _so_ is not a pro-form, so that you've lost me there.

Comment: @JK2 I get what you're angling at, but no, not exactly. Let me try and explain why (I'm not sure I'll succeed!). A pro-form carries out a syntactic job in a sentence (like being a *Subject*, or a *Direct Object*, or a *Modifier*). It differs from other groups of words that can do that job by a) not having a fixed meaning or referent, and b) by usually standing in for a whole phrase or clause instead of just a word (so for example, pronouns stand in for whole noun phrases, not just nouns). Whilst pro-forms are often deictic in some sense ...

Comment: @JK2 ... (they can be anaphoric, referring backwards, or cataphoric, referring forwards, or exophoric, referring to something outside of the immediate discourse), this doesn't mean that all deictic words are pro-forms. So for example, *however* normally contrasts what's coming next with what has been said before. But we don't interpret *however* as standing in for another group of words interpretable from the context. And *but*, in some sense, can be thought of as relating what is coming with what has gone before without standing in for previously mentioned words. ...

Comment: @JK2 ... Similarly, resultative *so* doesn't syntactically stand in for a group of words even though it contrasts what came before with what's coming up next. You can't replace resultative *so* with another phrase that came earlier. In contrast, pro-clause *so* actually does the same syntactic job as the clause (which you can reconstruct from the context) would do. I don't know if I'm being very clear?

Comment: If you still think that (74)'s _so_ has an anaphoric relationship with the foregoing clause, I don't understand why (74)'s _so_ cannot pass muster as a pro-form if it can be thought of as a) not having a fixed meaning or referent and b) standing in for the whole preceding clause. OR can it never be thought of as such?

Comment: @JK2 It doesn't syntactically stand in for the whole clause though. You cannot take *so* out and put a clause in its place. No?

Comment: Araucaria, I wouldn't think that being able to replace a pro-form with its antecedent is a necessary condition for proving that the pro-form is legit. In fact, CGEL itself says (p 1463): "We will use this ‘pro-X’ formulation only when both the antecedent and the potential replacement belong to the same category X. This is the usual case, but there are some places where it does not apply:"...

Comment: ...And one of the two examples in [32] on the same page happens to have the 'so much so that' construction, for which CGEL says "when modified by _so much_ in this way the pro-form _so_ cannot be replaced by any matching form, whether a clause like the antecedent or not."

Comment: @JK2 The point there is that *so* cannot be replaced by another *so*-category element. But it is still syntactically the head of a clause, and the word *so* represents that clause. In the preposition example, the word *so* makes reference to another clause, but it doesn't *represent* that clause within the clause it's in. The anaphoric link with pro-clause *so* occurs precisely because the meaning of *so* is indexed semantically with a preceding clause. The word *so* can be thought of as standing in for a clause *it prospered*. The word *so* actually means *it prospered* there.

Comment: @JK2 ... But the preposition *so* does not **mean** "*there had been a power failure*", it just indicates that what is coming is a result of what was previously mentioned. So it refers to it indirectly, but it is not "standing in" for it.

Comment: @JK2 Don't know if I managed to express what I was trying to say there ... Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding **so that** and **so much so that** lies in grasping how many roles "so" can actually play, and identifying which role(s) it plays in the expressions you are considering.

In the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so), there's an etymology drawing on multiple European languages.  However, there's also parallel usage in French (*tel*, *tellement*) and the sound itself occurs in other languages that have influenced English in other ways, such as [Japanese](https://www.japanesepod101.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2893).

The general usage of *so* is to refer to something that has already been established between two speakers, or between the writer and the reader, as in Jean-Luc Picard's well-known "Make it so" from [Star Trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9695/whats-the-origin-of-picards-signature-phrase-make-it-so).

In the Wiktionary entry, *so* is first characterized as a *conjunction* and as an *adverb*, but examples of its other uses are given later.

The key to identifying the role of any given *so* is to transform the expression by replacing *so* with a more specific word or set of words that convey the same meaning. For example:

- **so** = "I accept what you just said, and the consequence will be what you say next."  Essentially a conjunction, like *therefore*.  If you can replace the *so* with *therefore*, you have narrowed down its role.  It can be a conjunction uniting two related but independent actions, or the introductory word in an adverbial clause, which modifies the first action (the Wiktionary gives *therefore* as an adverb).
- **so that** is *almost* the same as *so*, since in most English expressions *that* can be eliminated without changing the meaning.  In practice, however, *so that* connotes purpose.  Compare:

  - The air cooled, **so** the leaves changed color. *Conjunction*.  Replacing *so* with *and* does not change the meaning (very much).
  - The farmer placed nets below the trees, **so that** the apples would be caught before they reached the ground. *Adverb identifying the goal of the first action*.  Replacing *so* with *and* changes the meaning by de-emphasizing the will of the farmer.  Replacing *so* with *in order that* or *with the purpose of* keeps the meaning intact.
- **so much so that**: an expression that introduces an adverbial clause by referring to two previously expressed ideas.  It's probably best to view this as an idiom that allows you to make these references conveniently.  For example: in *The Coo-ee cordial factory prospered almost at once, so much so that my father bought a new house at Coorparoo*, we have:

  - the first *so* refers to the verb *prospered*, but it **plays a double role** as an adverb for the *so* that follows.  You could replace *so much so that* with *so remarkably that* and keep the meaning.
  - the second *so* refers to the adverbial phrase *almost at once*.  You could replace it with *better than his competitors* and still have a meaningful statement.
  - *much* is functioning as an adverb modifying the second *so*.  You could replace it with *ridiculously*, i.e. *...prospered almost at once, so ridiculously so that my father bought...*

As a further example, we could imagine a Jean-Luc Picard saying: "Make it so.  So much so that these creatures never return to this part of the Galaxy again."

So the challenge with identifying  *so* as a part of speech is that the prior reference is sometimes hard to infer. So perhaps it's best to think of expressions with *so* as special cases of **conjunctive propositions** introducing adverbial clauses.

Finally, don't forget that CGEL offers a somewhat narrow academic perspective on our language, and that there's actually quite a lot you can say with *so*, e.g.

- **Alphonse:** And so?
- **Gaston:**  So, since you *so* want to know, Miss So-and-so lives in that so-so district that we keep hearing so much about. So just let it be, okay?"
- **Alphonse:** Oooh... *soooo* intense.  So tell me how come, huh?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to isolate the antecedent, i.e. what so actually refers to.

> [64] ii The Coo-ee cordial factory prospered almost at once, so much **so** that my father bought a new house at Coorparoo.

refers to the verb "prospered": "he prospered... **so much so**", i.e. "to such a degree".

As [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/so) nicely states "If you say that a state of affairs is so, you mean that it is the way it has been described. " *So* is adverb ("it is so"), and *so much so" an adverb group.

The construction is **so much so** + **that**.

Whereas:

> There had been a power failure, so that all classes had had to be cancelled.

Here **so that** has become an inseparable idiom (conjunction) that refers to no word in particular in the previous clause, but to the clause itself ("with the consequence that"). It can also be noticed that there is no idea of degree, the logic is binary (power failure => cancellation).

In truth it's not fundamentally different, but merely a semantic shift: the word **so** has lost its own individuality as an adverb, and it is now agglutinated to **that**, forming a single unit that is now perceived as a conjunction.

Whichever way one wants to call this technically, the difference should appear obvious.

Comment: Just because the two _so_'s are 'different' does that mean the two _so_'s should always be different parts of speech?

Comment: I guess the answer would be "it depends". Does it really matter? A "part of speech" is essentially a technical rationalization of how words are being used in everyday usage or in written language. Sometimes there is an element of convention and even of arbitrary in grammatical descriptions (one choice has to be made, and one convention has to prevail). I find it easier to go below the level of conventions and understand what is really going on, and why it happened (see Feynman's remark that [names don't constitute knowledge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFIYKmos3-s)).